# Speak stops on first Hyphen with IntegerName

Tags: number-theory, sound, education

[`IntegerName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerName.html) returns the text of an integer.  However, when [`Speak`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Speak.html) is applied to the result it stops at the fist hyphen.

For example

```
IntegerName[12345, "Words"]
```

> ```
> "twelve thousand, three hundred forty-five"
> ```

But

```
Speak@IntegerName[12345, "Words"]
```

Only reads `"twelve thousand, three hundred forty"`

Similarly for

```
IntegerName[123456, "Words"]
```

> ```
> "one hundred twenty-three thousand, four hundred fifty-six"
> ```

but

```
Speak@IntegerName[123456, "Words"]
```

Only reads `"one hundred twenty"`

Can anyone else confirm this behaviour?  Win 8.1 Pro with *Mma* 11.0.1

I am attempting to use *Mma* to introduce primary school students computational thinking.

Comment: The problem seems to be the \hyphen in the output of IntegerName. If you replace this with a dash `-` it will read OK.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm the problem on my system.

```
$Version

(*  "11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)"  *)
```

As a **workaround** use [`StringReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html) to replace the hyphen

```
IntegerName[12345, "Words"] // FullForm

(*  "twelve thousand, three hundred forty\[Hyphen]five"  *)

Speak@StringReplace[IntegerName[12345, "Words"], "‐" :> " "]

Speak@StringReplace[IntegerName[123456, "Words"], "‐" :> " "]
```